# Gnosis-safe - Get all owners of Gnosis-safe

Tags: solidity, web3js, gnosis-safe

I have created a Gnosis-safe. In general I wonder, how I can interact contractually (using web3) with the Gnosis-safe contract. The Gnosis-safe address links to a proxy contract.

My question is how I can interact with the Gnosis-safe and get all owners of that safe.

Answer (score 0):

The following solution, interacting right with the contract GnosisSafeL2:

```
const code = await web3.eth.getCode(SAFE_ADDRESS)
if(code !== '0x') {
    const jsonGnosisSafeL2 = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./contracts/build/GnosisSafeL2.json'));
    const gnosisSafe = new Contract(jsonGnosisSafeL2.abi, SAFE_ADDRESS);
    console.log(await gnosisSafe.methods.getOwners().call());
}
```